# Load file into MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file-io

Instead of my script asking the user the number of coordinate points and then to type them, I wanted the user to type the name of a file and the file to be read.

The file looks like this:

```
1 2
4 6
7 3
```

This is the piece of the script that gets the user input. How can I ask the user the name of the file and use it as input?

```
disp('This program performs a least-squares fit of an ');
disp('input data set to a straight line.');
n_points = input('Enter the number of input [x y] points: ');

for ii = 1:n_points
    temp = input('Enter [x y] pair: ');
    x(ii) = temp(1);
    y(ii) = temp(2);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`uigetfile()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uigetfile.html), which opens your OS's file browser.

The hard way: if you want the user to manually type the file name you can use `input`:

```
file_name = input('Please type the file name', "s");
```

---

Side note on your `for` loop, in a `for` loop the number of iterations is know, in your case `n_points`. Rather than growing `x` and `y` within the loop, [preallocate](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html) them. This doesn't make much of a difference on very small arrays, but if you've got tens of thousands of iterations, you'll notice a significant slow-down. Thus, call `x = zeros(n_points, 1)`, same for `y`, before the loop. Better even would be to create `coordinates = zeros(n_points, 2)` and save `coordinates(ii,:) = temp` within the loop, keeping your coordinates together and reducing the amount of variables.

Comment: I see, but how do I pass the data in the file to the x and y storage?

Comment: @Anon that depends on what you've got in your file and what format it has. Usually `importdata(file_name)` should do and give you an n-by-2 matrix, with `x` on the first and `y` on the second column.